Quota exceeded for quota metric 'LLM utility requests' and limit 'LLM utility requests per minute per region' of service 'aiplatform.googleapis.com'
I am trying to use the vertex API Text embedding using Langchain4J, in Micronaut application
@Singleton
public record VertexAiEmbedding(GoogleCloudConfiguration googleCloudConfiguration, VertexAiConfig vertexAiConfig) implements IVertexAiEmbedding {
    private static Embedding embedding;
    @Override
    public float[] embedVector(String text) {
        EmbeddingModel embeddingModel = VertexAiEmbeddingModel.builder()
                .endpoint(vertexAiConfig.endPoint())
                .project(googleCloudConfiguration.getProjectId())
                .location(vertexAiConfig.location())
                .publisher(vertexAiConfig.publisher())
                .modelName(vertexAiConfig.modelName())
                .build();
        Response<Embedding> response = embeddingModel.embed(text);
        embedding = response.content();
        return embedding.vector();
    }

Exception: Caused by: com.google.api.gax.rpc.ResourceExhaustedException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: Quota exceeded for quota metric 'LLM utility requests' and limit 'LLM utility requests per minute per region' of service 'aiplatform.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:974067563912'.

I am using the free trial period in GCP.
Updated
Credit



Hi @San Jaisy, Have you checked this quota related similar issue ? Let me know if this helped you or not.

@DhirajSingh Yeah it's the same issue, but due to the free trail  I am not able to request a quota increase because of the free trial.

You should always implement Exponential Backoff and retry the request. 429 type errors can happen at any time for many reasons such as the type of billing, service overload, etc.

@JohnHanley It seems like more in the billing side, just a question does the free trial doesn't cover that ??

I don't know what you have deployed. From your code, it appears you are using the Vertex AI SDK. The free trial is very limited. I recommend enabling billing and receiving the $300 credit. Then monitor billing to know when you have run out of credits. You can also set up billing alerts to know how much you are spending. A $1,000 credit is also available for some of the AI services. See this link for more information.

@JohnHanley I have updated the credit as well as screen shot on the question, still facing the same issue.

OK - you do not have a billing problem. The next step is to request a quota increase.

@JohnHanley seems like I don't have an permission, do I need to connect to customer support to try the feature in trial period. Update the screenshot on question update section

Your new screenshot shows the wrong quota. Use the Google Cloud Console GUI to request quota increases. That is the only method if you do not have a Google support engineer or sales rep. However, based on the screenshot, you will not be approved. Follow my advice in my first comment.

It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP support case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue tracker describing your issue.

The issue with quota is related to your billing account and if you are using free account then this will restrict you.
Another thing you can try is fetching less data ( less number of records may be try testing on a limited records) using vertex AI.

What do you mean by fetching less data? I am just using text embedding with hello world text.

@SanJaisy - I think Rajnish meant "tokens".
